# Android ProGuard in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-proguard

hi I am using ProGuard in my android eclipse project.

```
project.properties:
proguard.config=D:/ANDROID_Files/android-sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
```

My project contains `itsrts-pptviewer.jar`.

When I export my project console display

> java.io.IOException: Can't read [D:\TESTING_WORKSPACE\ProguardSample\libs\itsrts-pptviewer.jar] (Can't process class [com/olivephone/office/a/b/e/p.class] (Unknown verification type [17] in stack map frame))

I am new in ProGuard. help me.

Answer (score 0):

I also facing similar issue

java.io.IOException: Can't read [D:\TESTING_WORKSPACE\LmsLauncherActivity\libs\itsrts-pptviewer.jar(;;;;;;**/*.class)] (Can't process class [com/olivephone/office/a/b/e/p.class] (Unknown verification type [17] in stack map frame))